# Shopifty theme.liquid: Duplicate google-site-verification meta tag + random ones after

Tags: shopify, google-merchant-center, google-site-verification-api

For google merchant center, to confirm & claim the website I've added the google-site-verification meta tag into the  section of my theme.liquid

Lower in the  section I have 4 duplicates of 1 meta tag (not the one I added) + other random google-site-verification meta tags that I never added.

The screenshot with the blue tick is the meta tag I've added:[meta tag I added screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxzSy.png)

then 2 screenshots below show the random ones that appeared: [sc1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT4OI.png), [sc2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIsii.png)

You can't see it well since the line is super long, but there are 4 duplicates and then some random google-site-verification meta tags after the duplicates.

Is this normal? I suck with code and I'm just wondering if this is a cause for concern, since I've been battling google merchant center misrepresentation for 2 months.

Just wondering if this is normal and if this is concerning to anyone